# Creating a socket VS creating a connection

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming

I'm new to socket programming and would like to ask some basic questions-

1. A socket is just one end point out of the millions of endpoints over the internet. ***True ?***
2. A socket(on client side) uniquely tells which application I'm running and on which machine out of the billions of simultaneously running applications on millions of devices on the internet. ***True ?***
3. Who makes socket, the programmer or are implicitly built by the underlying OS?
4. What does it mean to create a socket ? Both on the server and client side.
5. Based on above question on what creating socket means, does creating a socket means establishing connection between the client and server, 
   **IF YES**, who establishes the connection, the OS ?
   **IF NO**, again then who establishes the connection, who connects those two sockets ?
6. How does a single server with one particular socket handle multiple requests from clients simultaneously ?

Comment: @Jan but a good programmer must be aware of such concepts while doing socket programming :D .

Comment: @Jan Your comments are incomprehensible. Sockets are a basic network programming construct, and in fact they have zero meaning outside a programming context.

Comment: How about the explanation given in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171734/difference-between-a-socket-and-a-port ? Would that clear things up for you a bit? Or http://www.danzig.jct.ac.il/tcp-ip-lab/ibm-tutorial/3376c210.html

Comment: @zagrimsan Sir they were really helpful links. Thanks. So can I conclude that, " a port number uniquely identifies a process on a local machine" whereas " a socket uniquely identifies a process on a network".

Comment: There's no such thing as a bad question, but somehow I feel that the questions you're asking are not meaningful...  (I have next to no actual experience of socket programming though). I mean, a socket is a way of accessing a network connection. Thus it exists only in the host. In the Internet, there are connections, and in a given host, there are sockets that allow the process to access the connection. There are no sockets in the Internet. From the links you should've received an answer to #3-6, too.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. A socket is just one end point out of the millions of endpoints over the internet. True?

False. 'Endpoints over the Internet' is meaningless. A socket is an endpoint of a connection, which might have nothing to do with the Internet whatsoever. A socket can also be unconnected.

> 2. A socket(on client side) uniquely tells which application I'm running and on which machine out of the billions of simultaneously running applications on millions of devices on the internet. True?

False. A socket *is owned by* a process, which in turn runs in a specific  host. You're basically putting it back to front.

> 3. Who makes socket, the programmer or are implicitly built by the underlying OS?

Neither. The *application* asks the *operating system* to create a socket.

> 4. What does it mean to create a socket ? Both on the server and client side.

It means creating a socket. Unclear what you're asking here, or what kind of an answer you're expecting.

> 5. Based on above question on what creating socket means, does creating a socket means establishing connection between the client and server,

No.

> IF YES, who establishes the connection, the OS ?

See above.

> IF NO, again then who establishes the connection, who connects those two sockets ?

The application asks the operating system to connect the socket to a target IP address and port.

> 6. How does a single server with one particular socket handle multiple requests from clients simultaneously ?

The operating system creates a new socket for every accepted connection.

Comment: @EJB a server is a unique machine over the internet and so a fixed ip address. It hosts a particular service on port suppose 80. Now a combination of port and ip make up the socket so how ""The operating system creates a new socket for every accepted connection""" this works, as if a new socket is created everytime then how is it going to be   further identifiable for other connections. P.S. I'm not the downvoter :) .

Comment: @Brut3Forc3 Neither 'a server is a unique machine over the internet' nor 'a combination of port and IP make up the socket' is correct. What you're asking about is rather basic, and not something that was asked by the OP.

Comment: Yes but my doubts come from all these things only. Would you mind in engaging in a chat with me on the same,  would be really appreciated :D

Comment: Certainly not. *Your* doubts are your problem, not part of this question  or this answer. If you have a question of your own, ask it. This is not the place.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Does it create a new connection for every created socket? Is a socket basically a connection? Is it a 1-1 relationship? Or can you create multiple sockets on one connection?